# Prolog - transforming a binary function into an n-ary one

Tags: prolog

I have to write a predicate that given a binary formula (ANDs/ORs in this case) in input transforms it into an n-ary one, if the same function is applied on either of the arguments. So, for example, `and(and(A, B), and(C, D))` becomes `and(A, B, C, D)`.

Can anyone give me indications on how to proceed with this without telling me exactly what to write? I'd like to understand how to go about it, but I really find it hard. What I got until now is just a base case - which I don't know if it's right:

```
simplify(A, B) :-
    A=..[Name, Arg1, Arg2],
    Name == and, 
    not(compound(Arg1)),
    not(compound(Arg2)),
    B = A.
```

That is, if I have an AND and both arguments are not compounds, then it means the simplified function is the same. How do I proceed further?

Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't simplify have two parameters? One to "return" the simplified version?

Comment: Yes yes, you are right. I need to parse the function inside instead of using the unification. I got quite confused!

Comment: First you need to decide what kinds of terms you're wanting to process and what results would be in those cases. For example, `and(and(A,B), and(C,D))` is easily understood to be `and(A,B,C,D)`. But what about `and(and(A,B), or(and(C,D), E))`? Are you looking to simplify expressions as well as combine arguments? Once you've decided that, think recursively. `simplify(and(A,B), Expression) :- ... simplify(A), ..., simplify(B), ...`, etc, to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my temporary solution. It's still not ideal, it "flattens" the function on the first depth level, so if there are any other ANDs or ORs more in depth in the formula, it doesn't get to them. How to make it work?

```
simplify(A, B, Functor) :-  A=..[Name, Arg1, Arg2], Name == Functor, 
                            not(compound(Arg1)), not(compound(Arg2)), B = A.
simplify(A, B, Functor) :-  A=..[Name, Arg1, Arg2], Name == Functor, 
                            Arg1=..[Name|_], Arg2=..[Name|_],
                            simplify(Arg1, C, Functor), simplify(Arg2, D, Functor),
                            C=..[_|ArgsC], D=..[_|ArgsD],
                            append(ArgsC, ArgsD, ArgsB),
                            B =.. [Functor|ArgsB].
simplify(A, B, Functor) :-  A=..[Name, Arg1, Arg2], Name == Functor, 
                            Arg1=..[Name|_],
                            simplify(Arg1, C, Functor),
                            C=..[_|ArgsC],
                            append(ArgsC, [Arg2], ArgsB),
                            B =.. [Functor|ArgsB].
simplify(A, B, Functor) :-  A=..[Name, Arg1, Arg2], Name == Functor, 
                            Arg2=..[Name|_],
                            simplify(Arg2, C, Functor),
                            C=..[_|ArgsC],
                            append([Arg1], ArgsC, ArgsB),
                            B =.. [Functor|ArgsB].
```

EDIT: This solution should work (not complete, I'm still writing every case). If you see the formula as a binary tree structure, it flattens every node that has the same key (AND or OR) into a single one, while keeping separated nodes that have different keys (to not mix ANDs arguments with ORs). It's quite verbose though, since I'm writing a case for every scenario (for example, `[Arg1 is not a compound, Arg2 is an AND]`, `[Arg1 is not a compound, Arg2 is an OR]`, et cetera), but I don't know if you can do it more elegantly. If it's possible, tell me!

```
% Case X(a, b) => X(a, b)
simplify(A, B) :-   A=..[Name, Arg1, Arg2], subset([Name], [or, and]), 
                            not(compound(Arg1)), not(compound(Arg2)), B = A, !.

% Case X(X(a, b), c) => X(a, b, c)
simplify(A, B) :-   A=..[Name, Arg1, Arg2], subset([Name], [or, and]), 
                            Arg1=..[Name|_], not(compound(Arg2)),
                            simplify(Arg1, C), C=..[_|ArgsC], 
                            append(ArgsC, [Arg2], ArgsB),
                            B =.. [Name|ArgsB], !.

% Case X(a, X(b, c)) => X(a, b, c)
simplify(A, B) :-   A=..[Name, Arg1, Arg2], subset([Name], [or, and]), 
                            not(compound(Arg1)), Arg2=..[Name|_], 
                            simplify(Arg2, C), C=..[_|ArgsC],
                            append([Arg1], ArgsC, ArgsB),
                            B =.. [Name|ArgsB], !.

% Case X(X(a, b), X(c, d)) => X(a, b, c, d)
simplify(A, B) :-   A=..[Name, Arg1, Arg2], subset([Name], [or, and]), 
                            Arg1=..[Name|_], Arg2=..[Name|_],
                            simplify(Arg1, C), simplify(Arg2, D),
                            C=..[_|ArgsC], D=..[_|ArgsD],
                            append(ArgsC, ArgsD, ArgsB),
                            B =.. [Name|ArgsB], !.

% Case X(X(a, b), Y(b, c)) => X(a, b, Y(b, c))              
simplify(A, B) :-   A=..[Name, Arg1, Arg2], subset([Name], [or, and]), 
                            Arg1=..[Name|_], Arg2=..[DifferentName|_], Name \== DifferentName,
                            simplify(Arg1, C), 
                            subset([DifferentName], [or, and]), simplify(Arg2, D),
                            C=..[_|ArgsC],
                            append(ArgsC, [D], ArgsB),
                            B =.. [Name|ArgsB], !.

% Case X(Y(a, b), X(c, d)) => X(Y(a, b), c, d)
simplify(A, B) :-   A=..[Name, Arg1, Arg2], subset([Name], [or, and]), 
                            Arg1=..[DifferentName|_], Arg2=..[Name|_], 
                            simplify(Arg2, C),
                            subset([DifferentName], [or, and]), simplify(Arg1, D),
                            C=..[_|ArgsC],
                            append([D], ArgsC, ArgsB),
                            B =.. [Name|ArgsB], !.

% Case X(Y(a, b), Y(c, d)) => X(Y(a, b, c, d))
simplify(A, B) :-   A=..[Name, Arg1, Arg2], subset([Name], [or, and]), 
                            Arg1=..[DifferentName|_], Arg2=..[DifferentName|_],
                            simplify(Arg1, C), simplify(Arg2, D),
                            C=..[_|ArgsC], D=..[_|ArgsD],
                            append(ArgsC, ArgsD, ArgsB),
                            E =..[DifferentName|ArgsB],
                            B =.. [Name|[E]], !.
```

Comment: This just doesn't look right. I don't see how you can handle the general case without recursion, unless you haven't stated your assumptions clearly in your question.

Comment: I've edited the code to be more clear. It works, but there are quite many cases and I don't know if you can generalize even more. Maybe by keeping a track of the father functor, or something like that?

Comment: That's what I'm saying. There are many cases and it seems recursion is the way to handle them. You can do it without recursion if you limit how deep you embed terms within parentheses, but like I say, your question didn't provide any guidance for limiting the scope of the problem. The general problem requires recursion. See my comment to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

For a more general solution (SWI-Prolog), we can start defining two auxiliary predicates:

```
% term_to_list(+Term, -List): convert a Term to a nested List

term_to_list(Term, List) :-
    (   compound(Term)
    ->  compound_name_arguments(Term, Name, Arguments),
        maplist(term_to_list, Arguments, Sublists),
        List = [Name|Sublists]
    ;   List = Term ).

% list_to_term(+List, -Term): convert a nested List to a Term

list_to_term(List, Term) :-
    (   compound(List)
    ->  List = [Name|Sublists],
        maplist(list_to_term, Sublists, Arguments),
        compound_name_arguments(Term, Name, Arguments)
    ;   Term = List).
```

These predicates works as following:

```
?- term_to_list(and(and(A,B),or(and(C,D),or(E,F))), List).
List = [and,[and,A,B],[or,[and,C,D],[or,E,F]]].

?- list_to_term([and,[and,A,B],[or,[and,C,D],[or,E,F]]], Term).
Term = and(and(A,B),or(and(C,D),or(E,F))).
```

After transforming the term into a corresponding nested list, we have a **uniform representation for both binary and n-ary boolean functions** used in the expression being simplified. Thus, the simplification can be done by the following predicates:

```
% simplify(+Expression, -Simplified): convert Expression into a Simplified one

simplify(Expression, Simplified) :-
    term_to_list(Expression, List),
    recursive_simplify(none, List, [NewList]),
    list_to_term(NewList, Simplified).

recursive_simplify(OuterOperator, Term, Simplified) :-
    (   compound(Term)
    ->  Term = [InnerOperator|Arguments],
        maplist(recursive_simplify(InnerOperator), Arguments, NewArguments),
        (   OuterOperator \= InnerOperator
        ->  append([[InnerOperator]|NewArguments], List),
            Simplified = [List]
        ;   append(NewArguments, Simplified) )
    ;   Simplified = [Term]).
```

Here are some examples:

```
?- simplify( and(and(A,B),or(and(C,D),or(E,F))), Simplified ).
Simplified = and(A,B,or(and(C,D),E,F)).

?- simplify( and(and(A,B),or(and(C,and(D,E)),or(F,G))), Simplified).
Simplified = and(A,B,or(and(C,D,E),F,G)).

?- simplify( and(and(A,B),or(C,or(and(and(D,E),F),G)),and(H,I)), Simplified).
Simplified = and(A,B,or(C,and(D,E,F),G),H,I).
```